# Handle of TComponent instance

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-2009

I have an instance of `TComponent` class and need to interact with the respective control via WinAPI calls.

In order to do this, I need a handle of the control represented by `TComponent` instance.

How can I get that handle from `TComponent`?

Comment: You shoult test before If C is TWinControll then....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try casting your TComponent instance to TWinControl.

Untested if it returns *valid* handles, but it's returning plausible numbers.

```
 procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
   var
     i: integer;
     mycontrol: TWinControl;
   begin
     Memo1.Lines.Clear;
     for i := 0 to ComponentCount - 1 do
       if Components[i] is TWinControl then
          begin
            mycontrol := TWinControl(Components[i]);
            Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(mycontrol.Handle));
          end;
   end;
```

Comment: Use of Form1.ControlCount and Form1.Controls[i] would filter out unwanted nonvisual TComponents. You'd still need the IS test and cast to TWinControl.

Comment: @dthorpe But that would not, for example, give you a button on a panel (because the button will be in the panel's `Controls` rather than the form's). If using a recursive approach, it would also give you internal helper controls that you shouldn't normally be touching.

Comment: @dthorpe Indeed `Controls` is about parent/child relationships, while `Components` is about ownership. This is an entirely different relationship. Controls is not a subset of Components, and even recursively traversing Controls will not necessarily give you the same controls.